# Open() command buffer manual buffer manipulation does not work

Tags: python

I am currently creating a data logging function with the Raspberry Pi, and I am unsure as to whether I have found a slight bug. The code I am using is as follows:

```
import sys, time, os

_File = 'TemperatureData1.csv'
_newDir = '/home/pi/Documents/Temperature Data Logs'
_directoryList = os.listdir(_newDir)

os.chdir(_newDir)

# Here I am specifying the file, that I want to write to it, and that
# I want to use a buffer of 5kb
output = open(_File, 'w', 5000)

try:
    while (1):
    output.write('hi\n')
    time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Keyboard has been pressed')
    output.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```

What I have found is that when I periodically view the created file properties, the file size increases in accordance with the default buffer setting 8192 bytes, and not the 5kb that I have specified. However, when I run the exact same program in Python 2.7.13, the buffer size changes to 5kb as requested.

I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this and had any ideas on a solution to getting the program working on Python 3.6.3? Thanks in advance. I can work with the problem on python 2.7.13, it is my pure curiosity which has led to me posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Python's definition of `open` in version 2 is what you are using:

> `open(name[, mode[, buffering]])`

In Python 3, the `open` command is a little different, in that `buffering` is not a positional integer, but a keyword arg:

> `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) have the following note:

> `buffering` is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass `0` to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), `1` to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > `1` to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as follows:
>
> Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.
>   “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use line buffering. Other text files use the policy described above for binary files.

That special `8192` number is simply 2^13.

I would suggest trying `buffering=5000`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I must of missed that when reading the documentation.  What is interesting though, is that trying buffering=5000 also does not work; however when I place the integer 1 (on its own, without the buffering keyword) line buffering works.  Do you believe that there could be an underlying error in the way that the io library is functioning in python 3 or above?  Have you been able to manually manipulate buffers in your projects? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some more research, and managed to find some reasons as to why setting 'buffering' to a value more than 1, does not manually manipulate the buffer to a desired size (bytes) in python 3 or above.

It seems to be because the io library uses two buffers when working with files, a text buffer, and a binary buffer.  When in text mode, the file is flushed in accordance to the text buffer (which does not seem to be able to be manipulated when buffering > 1).  Instead the buffering argument, manipulates the binary buffer, which then feeds into the text buffer, therefore the buffering function does not work how the programmer expects.  This is further explained in the following link:

https://bugs.python.org/issue30718

There is however a work around; you need to use open() in binary mode and not text mode, then use the io.TextIOWrapper function to write to a txt or csv file using the binary buffer.  The work around is as follows:

```
 import sys, time, os, io

_File = 'TemperatureData1.csv'

# Open or overwrite the file _file, and use a 20kb buffer in RAM
# before data is saved to disk.
output = open(_File, mode='wb', buffering=700)
output = io.TextIOWrapper(output, write_through=True)

try:
    while (1):
        output.write('h\n')
        time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Keyboard has been pressed')
    output.close()
    sys.exit(1)
```